# Transform data in Excel (rows and columns)

Tags: excel, transform

**Current input:**

```
+-------------------------+
|          col A          |
+-------------------------+
| Test(read)              |
| - ABC(dsakl)            |
| - ABC(dslø) Write(T)    |
| - ABC(dsjkl)            |
| Test(true)              |
| - ABC(DSdsa)            |
| - ABC(dsalk**) write(F) |
+-------------------------+
```

**Wanted output:**

```
+-------------------------+-------------------------+
|          col A          |          col B          |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| Test(read)              | - ABC(dsakl)            |
| Test(read)              | - ABC(dslø) Write(T)    |
| Test(read)              | - ABC(dsjkl)            |
| Test(true)              | - ABC(DSdsa)            |
| Test(true)              | - ABC(dsalk**) write(F) |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+
```

Hence, I want to transform my data so everytime "Test" occurs it creates a new row in column "A" corresponding to the number of rows until the next "Test" occurs. The cells containing "ABC" should be written in column "B" in the output file.

Really appreciate input on this one. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There may be other approaches to this, but if you want to do it purely with regular formulas you could try this:

Do col B with Aggregate to find the first row with a "-", then the second etc.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A$1:A$10,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(A$1:A$10)/(LEFT(A$1:A$10)="-"),ROW())),"")
```

Col A is more difficult - this finds the nth row starting with "-" as before, then looks before this to find the last row starting with T:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A$1:A$10,AGGREGATE(14,6,ROW($A$1:INDEX(A$1:A$10,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(A$1:A$10)/(LEFT(A$1:A$10)="-"),ROW())))
/(LEFT($A$1:INDEX(A$1:A$10,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(A$1:A$10)/(LEFT(A$1:A$10)="-"),ROW())))="T"),1)),"")
```

[image]